# Having trouble while visualizing my 1 GB mb csv file data using Leaflet in R. I have 8GB RAM with 256 GB SD card

Tags: r, time-series, rstudio, gis

I am dealing with Time series data CSV files having 1 GB size. I want to visualize the data using leaflet library to show just first 10000 rows but it gives me error in the form of memory allocation. I have used the following code for visualizing data which worked perfect for low size files but doesn't work for large files

```
library(leaflet)
crime_Data_leaflet <- Data[1:10000,] # display the first 10,000 rows
Data$popup <- paste("<b>crime type #: </b>", Data$`Crime type`, "<br>",
                    "<br>", "<b>Month: </b>", Data$Month,
                    "<br>", "<b>Longitude: </b>", Data$Longitude,
                    "<br>", "<b>Latitude: </b>", Data$Latitude)

leaflet(Data, width = "100%") %>% addTiles() %>%
  addTiles(group = "OSM (default)") %>%
  addProviderTiles(provider = "Esri.WorldStreetMap",group = "World StreetMap") %>%
  addProviderTiles(provider = "Esri.WorldImagery",group = "World Imagery") %>%
  # addProviderTiles(provider = "NASAGIBS.ViirsEarthAtNight2012",group = "Nighttime Imagery") %>%
  addMarkers(lng = ~Longitude, lat = ~Latitude, popup = Data$popup, clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()) %>%
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("OSM (default)","World StreetMap", "World Imagery"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
  )
```

After running this it gives me the following error.

> Error in (function (..., sep = " ", collapse = NULL)  :    could not
>   allocate memory (958 Mb) in C function 'R_AllocStringBuffer' Error
>   during wrapup: could not allocate memory (695 Mb) in C function
>   'R_AllocStringBuffer'

My laptop is Lenovo laptop with 8 GB RAM and 256 GB SD memory.

I have removed the unused data by using

```
mem_change(rm(London_Crime_Data))
```

size of this data was 1.4 GB.

The total memory used until now is

```
mem_used()
1.37 GB
```

But still facing the same problem. 
Also I will use ARIMA model after this process than again I will face the same issue with memory I think.

One more question is that I have load all my csv files and merged it into a single file using the following code.

```
tbl <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv") %>%
  lapply(read_csv)%>%
  bind_rows
```

Now I want to save these CSV files on my desktop for further analysis. How can I do it ?

Please give me detail and exact solution for both of my questions. As I am new to R and I searched alot for these issues but could not found the exact and simple solution which made me confused.

Comment: Are you running 32bit version of R?

Comment: Yes its 64 bit. I have checked it by using the following command                                                                               Sys.getenv("R_ARCH")
[1] "/x64"

Comment: How many rows is `Data`? That's what all your references in your leaflet code are to, not your 10000-row subset `crime_Data_leaflet`.

Comment: Also, just trying to show 10,000 random marker points on my laptop of similar specs took about 25 seconds to render the map, without the string popup. I think this may not be a good approach, and you should try summarizing your spatial data before mapping.

Comment: total rows are more than 0.6 million

Comment: Also to your second question, you use `write.csv` to save dataframes back to your disk for storage.

Comment: Bran I have done that. Thank you but the problem is that it gives me only 100k rows. Though my original data has 1 million plus rows.